# riemannienne geometry , differential calculus

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I'm searching for a books for the riemannienne geometry and differential calculus .
If any one know some good books I really need those books

Answer (score 0):

The manifold series of books by John Lee (Topological, Smooth, and Riemannian).  Petersen's Riemannian geometry is a good one to go along with it as well.  For the more advanced reading, Sakai or Klingenberg are great.  If you'd like to contrast general relativity (Lorentzian geometry) to Riemannian Geometry, O'Neill's text is fantastic.